# Python / Django handling errors UNIQUE constraints

Tags: python, django, database

Good Day.

I'm writing a little script that pulls RSS data using Feedparser.

I got it working up to where it pulls everything I need to my database and store it there.

Now to avoid data from being duplicated, I set Unique = True in my models.

Of course, now I'm dealing with the error

`return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: jobrss_rssjob.link`

Okay, sort of good it's not duplicating data. However, it completely crashes the script so it will just stop.

Obviously I now need to write an exception for errors - and that's pretty much where I'm stuck cause they are also throwing errors at me.

Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import feedparser
from django.utils import timezone
import json
from django.db import IntegrityError

from jobrss.models import RSSJob

try:
        def run():

            sources = [
        "https://mybroadband.co.za/vb/external.php?type=RSS2&forumids=269",
        "http://www.bizcommunity.com/rssjobs.aspx?l=196&c=11&s=Developer&sm=1"
            ]
            data = []
            for url in sources:
                data.append(feedparser.parse(url))
                for data in data:
                    for post in data.entries:
                        title = post.title
                        link = post.link
                        add = RSSJob()
                        add.title = title
                        add.link = link
                        add.save()
                        print("Added successfully")
except IntegrityError:
    print("Data Already exists")
```

Any recommendation how I can improve this?

Oh and these are the errors.
When I run the script on an empty database:

```
(techvenv) Ronalds-MacBook-Pro:TWNEW burgundy$ python manage.py runscript rsspull
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Added successfully
Exception while running run() in 'scripts.rsspull'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 398, in __getattr__
    return self.__getitem__(key)
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 356, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'append'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 63, in run_from_argv
    super(EmailNotificationCommand, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 75, in execute
    super(EmailNotificationCommand, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/utils.py", line 59, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 238, in handle
    run_script(mod, *script_args)
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 148, in run_script
    mod.run(*script_args)
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/TWNEW/scripts/rsspull.py", line 18, in run
    data.append(feedparser.parse(url))
  File "/Users/burgundy/dev/Projects/techvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 400, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("object has no attribute '%s'" % key)
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'append
```

And this is when I run it again:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: jobrss_rssjob.link
```

Kind Regards. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you're catching the exception before defining and running the function. You need to move the the `try...except` block inside the `run()` function.

Consider this:

```
>>> try:
        def run():
            print(1 / 0)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print "Can't divide by zero"

>>> run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

The reason it is happening is, when we define a function, Python doesn't actually run the function. So, `1 / 0` doesn't raise any error while we are defining the function. Here, the `try...except` block will only catch any errors **during the function definition**. But when we call the `run()` function, we are running it outside the `try...except` block. That is why we get the error.

---

**How to fix it:**

Move the `try...except` block inside the  inner-most `for` loop of the  `run()` function. Example:

```
def run():
    for url in sources:
        data.append(feedparser.parse(url))
        for data in data:
                for post in data.entries:
                    try:
                        title = post.title
                        ...
                        print("Added successfully")
                    except IntegrityError:
                        print("Data Already exists")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes so much more sense now. 
I really appreciate it.
Have a good day. :)